# Visual Basic MS Report Builder - How can we set Min(Date) as the default value for a parameter

Tags: vba, powerbi, reportbuilder3.0

I am connected a power bi dataset to the MS Report Builder and I need to find a way to set the min date of my date column as default value in my parameter. I setup the a from and to date as date range to filter my data.

I tried

```
First(Fields!Date.Value, "DataSet1")
```

but I get this error

```
A 'Value' expression used for the report parameter 'FromDate' refers to a field.  Fields cannot be used in report parameter expressions.
```

What's the right way of writing this expression?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Dataset that returns the min date and use that.

[image]

Comment: I swear I did that at one time and got an error :D I love coding. Here is the code I used to create the date EVALUATE
{
MINX(
 KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('table'[columnA])),
 CALCULATE(MIN('table'[columnB]))
)
}